# Drag and drop api HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to design a page with drag and drop functionality. The problem i am facing is that i don't want to allow the user to drag and drop on same cell if he has already dragged and dropped an image on the same cell earlier.

Thanks

Comment: Good to know, but that's not a question. I think you need to do a bit more of your own research first. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask/

Answer (score 1):

Use the dragenter event to validate if it can be dropped.

`dragenter`

Fired when the mouse is first moved over the target element while a drag is occuring. A listener for this event should indicate whether a drop is allowed over this location. If there are no listeners, or the listeners perform no operations, then a drop is not allowed by default.

Comment: can you please tell me how can i check if the user has already dropped an item in that div...